# How can I compare and delete duplicate files between multiple folders on El Capitan?

Tags: macos, bash

I'm dealing with two different types of file on OS X El Capitan. They have the same file extension but have tags at the end of the file name (e.g., `abc123_m.psarc` and `abc123_p.psarc`). I have one folder (`folder 1`) with both `*_m` and `*_p` versions of the same files (same name, just different tag) and another folder (`folder 2`) with only `*_m` files.

How can I delete all of the `_p` files from `folder 1` if they have an `_m` twin in `folder 2`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Terminal one-liner that lists the contents of folder_2, changes _m to _p, and silently removes files from folder_1. If there's no corresponding _p file in folder_1, nothing happens.

Use a full path for folder_2 or ../folder_2 if both folders are subfolders of the same parent.

```
cd folder_1; ls -1 folder_2 | sed /_m/s//_p/ | xargs rm -f
```