# Deleting duplicates in parent folder OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I'm looking to do something that I'm sure is pretty straightforward - hopefully with a Terminal command similar to this: [How can I compare and delete duplicate files between multiple folders on El Capitan?](https://superuser.com/questions/1098728/how-can-i-compare-and-delete-duplicate-files-between-multiple-folders-on-el-capi).

I've been keeping photos in a number of directories, in one of two formats:

Short Trips:

- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Location/pic1.jpg

Long Trips:

- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Trip Name/Location1/pic1.jpg
- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Trip Name/Location2/pic1.jpg

Most of these folders contain a subfolder called 'Best', where I have copied my favourite photos from the parent folder, thereby duplicating each photo.

e.g.

Short Trips:

- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Location/Best

Long Trips:

- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Trip Name/Location1/Best
- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Trip Name/Location2/Best

N.B. Some of the smaller albums don't contain this 'Best' folder.

What I want to do is to scan recursively through each folder looking for a 'Best' folder. If it is found, then I want to go through each of the files within this folder and delete the corresponding item from the parent folder.

e.g. Parent folder contains:

- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Location1/pic1.jpg
- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Location1/pic2.jpg
- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Location1/pic3.jpg

and the 'Best' folder contains

- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Location1/Best/pic1.jpg
- /Users/Ben/Pictures/Location1/Best/pic3.jpg

Then I want to delete pic1 and pic3 from the parent folder and only keep pic2.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your folder design could be improved: you would have been better to have created links instead of copies in `Best/`, which would have used negligible space, but kept all the originals together for each location. Your question is wrong: when you give `~/` as the prefix to the folder contents, I presume you mean `./`, otherwise the folders would be identical. Furthermore, I find it difficult to work out from your question where the `Best/` folders reside. Please update your question to clarify these issues.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the main post as per your request. Hopefully it's clear now. I appreciate the structure isn't good in hindsight. I'd happily look at replacing the duplicates with symlinks too if that makes it easier.

Comment: To correctly list those paths, they should all start `~/Pictures/` which implies `/Volumes/[MacHD]/Users/[UserName]/` without having to know the actual name of either the hard drive or user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have clarified your question, I think I can see what you need:-

```
find /Users/Ben/Pictures/ -type d -name Best | \
     while read -r d; \
     do for f in "$d"/*; \
        do cmp "$f" "${f%/Best/*}/${f##*/Best/}" && \
           ln -sf "${f%/Best/*}/${f##*/Best/}" "$f"; \
        done; \
     done
```

This works as follows:-

- Use `find` to locate all the `Best/` subdirectories.
- For each subdirectory found, compare each of its files with the original in the parent folder.
- If they are identical, overwrite the file in `Best/` with a link to the file in the parent folder.
- If you prefer hard to symbolic links you can use `ln -f ...` instead of `ln -sf ...` (either will suit your purposes).
- The key parse elements are `${f%/Best/*}`, which removes `/Best/FileName` from the end of the path (should be the same as `$d`), and `${f##*/Best/}`, which isolates the file name from the path (should be the same as `${f##*/}`).
- I don't usually write complete scripts as answers, but I can't see any easy way to guide you through the writing of it; make sure you understand it before you use it - add `echo` in front of the critical `ln` command to make sure it will do what you expect.

I have tested this on Ubuntu, but OS/X implementations of `cmp` and `ln` should work with the same parameters.

Just in case you get get things wrong, back up the directories before you start.